# Shortcut to swap windows side by side for split view mode?

Tags: split-view

Suppose I have Chrome on the left and Firefox on the right for split view. How do I swap it so that its Firefox on the left and Chrome on the right

I know you can do it manually by putting one window on a desktop then re positioning it but I was hoping for a shortcut